# ms access sql Check if string contains only valid characters

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a field which should not have any other letters/digits other than B to its right once B occurred.
i.e. valid value : 0000BBBB
Invalid value : 0000BAG0

So far, I have succeeded to substring from B's occurrence. But I'm stuck at how to check if each character is B.

Below is the query I have written so far:

```
IIF(
MID(Field, INSTR(Field, 'B'), LEN(Field)) NOT LIKE '*[B]*',
"FAIL",
"PASS"
)
```

But this results in pass for 0000BBBBA which is actually Fail.

Comment: Can you simple use the RIGHT function to look at the last character of the string? If b ==  pass, if not b == fail?

Comment: my requirement is to check each character whether it is B or not. not only at the end.

Comment: Hmm well you said "should not have any other letters/digits once B occured" so logically, checking the last character would satisfy your requirement, right?

Comment: oh sry, my mistake, didn't convey it properly. After B, only B should come.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. But still, it sounds like the last character in the field can only be "B" regardless of if the string is "123456b" or "bbbbbbb" -- those are valid, while "1235ba" or "bbbbbbba" is invalid... correct?

Comment: Yes correct....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The character class `[!B]` matches any character other than the letter *B*.  So take the substring you get from `Mid()` and check whether it is `Not Like '*[!B]*'` --- IOW whether it contains any character other than *B*.

```sql
SELECT
    t.Field,
    IIf(Mid(t.Field, InStr(t.Field, 'B')) Not Like '*[!B]*', 'PASS', 'FAIL')
FROM
FROM YourTable AS t
```

Comment: Thank you! I guessed that it was something small that I'm missing..silly me..thanks a lot.